# EF7 change connectionstring at runtime

Tags: runtime, connection-string, entity-framework-core

In the previous versions of EF we were able to alter the dbcontext connection string as below :

```
context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "the new connectionstring";
```

How can we do this with EF7?

Thank you

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to change the connection string after initializing a DbContext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution :
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Configuring-a-DbContext#config-from-external-code

Context Code

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions options)
    : base(options)
{ }

public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

Application code

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Blogging;integrated security=True;");
var context = new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

Thank you